# Root access to just the dataflow instances

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to configure an access policy that would allow the job creator (or less preferably anybody with access to the project) access to the created instances, without granting similar access to the rest of the machines in the Google Cloud project (e.g., production machines)?

Thanks again,
G

Answer (score 2):

The access policies that you define for the project are carried over to the instances backing up a job submitted in that project.

Details on the policies and related actions are outlined in the GCE documentation: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access

Cheers,
r